# Beta sites are no longer beta if 7 years old or more

Tags: discussion

[Psychology & Neuroscience is no longer considered Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708) even though they are not meeting the 10 questions per day criteria.

The criteria is changing and we stand to move to non-beta status once we reach 7 years old.

How old is MedicalSciences.SE?

Answer (score 3):

[According to Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/medical-sciences), MedicalSciences.SE is 4 years old and therefore will stand to move to non-beta in 2022 unless it meets the criteria before then.

Comment: According to the linked metaSE post we shouldn't count on that. Mere age was AFAIU a one-off measure. Neither '10 Qpd' nor '7 years beta' are any longer hard and fast rules. They are conceptualising a new scheme altogether, unfinished and non-public now?